# Función en Apps script google sheet

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-api

Tengo problemas con una api, solo necesito realizar una función en App script para relacionar una hoja de calculo de google (sheets) con la parte de administración de Google

Necesito que me genere la lista de los usuarios de la parte de administración desde el directorio, solo seria eso, que me genere la lista en la hoja de sheets de los campos que tengo en administración de Google (nombre y tipo de licencia) si es posible también añadir la cantidad de GB que tiene en almacenamiento ese usuario, este es el código que tengo

```
function getLicenseAssignments() {
  try{
  var values = [];
  var productId = 'Google-Apps';
  var customerId = 'saviasaludeps.com';
  var assignments;
  
  do {
    var response = AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments
        .list(productId, customerId, {
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken,
    });
    assignments = response.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < assignments.length; i++) {
      var assignment = assignments[i];
      values.push([assignment.userId, assignment.skuName]);
    }
  pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  var libro =SpreadsheetApp.openById('1E8JdeMVr9wqnSrS7EyUEnHLrAQsJfT_kHwDkEBceqrI');
  sheet = libro.getSheetByName('Hoja 6');
  
  var headers = ['Correo', 'Licencia'];
  sheet.clear()
  sheet.appendRow(headers); 
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .alert('Función getLicenseAssignments ejecutada exitosamente');  
  
  } catch(e){
    
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .alert('Se produjo el error' + e.message + ' en la función LicenciasAsignadas');
    
    }  
  
}
```

El problema que tengo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, no pongas el núcleo de la pregunta (el problema) en un enlace externo o una captura de imagen, eso es lo más importante, y debe aparecer en la pregunta de la forma más comprensible posible: **como texto dentro de la misma pregunta**. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y mejora la redacción de la pregunta en ese sentido.

Comment: Por otra parte, revisa la documentación, pues `LicenseAssignments` no parece tener un método llamado `list`, sino **`listForProduct`**, [como se puede ver aquí en los ejemplos de código](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-license-manager).

Comment: Buenas tardes, no me funciona ni  `list` ni `listForProduct`

Comment: ¿Qué ocurre cuando usas `listForProduct`? Convendría que hagas un Log de `response` para ver qué trae ese objeto.

Comment: El mismo error, pero con listForProduct, el mismo comentario, solo reemplaza list por listForProduct

Comment: Pues coloca un `Logger.log(response);` y dinos qué muestra. Dinos también si has autorizado la API de Admin en ese contexto y con qué permisos.

Comment: `Se produjo el errorCannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listForProduct') en la función LicenciasAsignadas`    Y la API si tiene autorización en ese contexto y la cuenta tiene todos los permisos como super administrador.

Comment: Prueba a declarar pageToken antes del `do`,  tal y como indica la doc: **`let pageToken = null;`** y quita la coma al final de esto: `pageToken: pageToken,` compara tu código contra los ejemplos de la doc, que para eso existe.

Comment: Ya lo he comparado, y aún así no he podido continuar, no paso de error y no encuentro solución, ya he hecho los cambios que me has aportado.  `Se produjo el errorCannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listForProduct') en la función LicenciasAsignadas`

Comment: ¿Tienes el servicio habilitado [tal y como se explica aquí](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)? Considera [edit] la pregunta demostrando que has dado todos esos pasos con capturas de pantalla adecuadas. Puede que te falte habilitar algo y que por eso no esté funcionando.